# How to preserve the folder structure in the resources folder in a Quarkus Native Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, native, quarkus

I'm currently having this issue where my Quarkus Java native lambda can't read the content of the resources file, I know how to specify which files to import into my executable with the `quarkus.native.resources.includes=*` property, but it simply doesn't work. Of course when ran as a normal quarkus java program it just works. Any idea?

My suspect is related to folder structure not being preserved, the only examples in [Quarkus tips article](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips) are files, not folders.

This thing has been driving me crazy for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your recourses with:

- `quarkus.native.resources.includes=**`, note that there are two asterisk.

It will include all files in your current directory.